# How should I require or use the same module in multiple files for a single project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, require

I know that modules are cached when required, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30038787/1609548), but what would be the best way in terms of writing good or less code and code readability out of the following ways?

### Scenario:

I have three files **A**, **B** and **C** and all of them require the same other modules like `url` and `express` but file **A** is my main file which would also require the file **B** and **C** as modules along with `url` and `express` modules.

1. Should I require the same module (i.e. `url` and `express` ) in every file (i.e. **A**, **B** and **C**) ?
2. Should I require those modules (i.e. `url` and `express` ) only in the main file (i.e **A**) and pass those required modules to the file **B** and **C** while requiring them, like the following

```
var app = require('express'),
    url = require('url),
    b= require('B')(app, url),
    c= require('C')(app, url);
```

3. Any other good or alternative way?

I would really appreciate a good explanation of how would I be doing it the right and the best way or what are the best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say be explicit and always require the modules you need, it helps maintainability and modularity.  If you use

```
b = require('B')(app, url)
```

there is chance that there are modules needed by **B** but not by **A**, so you end up writing some requires anyway, and need to remember what you inherited and what's new.  Besides, you won't be able to use your module **B** by module **D**, which didn't need `app` and `url`.

Comment: I agree. It's also easy to remove\add required modules if they are not dependent on external ones